# A script that will only run when a player joins the game

Tags: lua, roblox

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    game.StarterPlayer.CameraMaxZoomDistance = 0
    end)
```

I want the player to be in first perspective only when they first join the game.
After they die they should be in third person. How do I go about this?

Comment: What library / engine are you using to accomplish this task?

Comment: Everyone on roblox uses the same engine, roblox studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    game.StarterPlayer.CameraMaxZoomDistance = 0
    end)
```

after line 1 and before game.StarterPlayer add a characteraddedfunction like so

```
player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character)
    character:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Died:connect(function()
        game.StarterPlayer.CameraMaxZoomDistance = (number you want for default)
    end)
end)
```

this waits for character to respawn and gets that character and puts it in the character variable, then the game waits for the Humanoid object to appear inside the character, then it waits for the Died event to take place which is the event that watches for a respawn or "death" then it sets the cameradistance back to normal based on the number you put.